# WP; How to prompt tweet option on form submit

Tags: wordpress, twitter, form-submit

I have an option for users to submit posts to a website I'm creating using the 'User Submitted Posts' plugin. When a user successfully submits a post from the front end, the page redirects to the post they just created, albeit via a twitter bootstrap modal.

I can add a button that will prompt users to tweet the post using:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=dreamscometrue&text=My%20dream%20is..." class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-size="large" data-related="jimmyedgar">Tweet #dreamscometrue</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

What I want is for that prompt to pop up automatically upon successfully submitting a post to be published by the front end user, instead of forcing them to click the tweet button.

The markup for the submit button is:

```
<input class="exclude" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'usp'); ?>">
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#user-submitted-post').on("click",function() { your twitter code });
```

Comment: Thanks Jude, are you suggesting this be added as js?

Comment: So I've added this to an enqueued js file, but I'm not sure what you mean by "your twitter code". The twitter code is part trigger, part js.

Comment: The trigger will be clicking the button, the JS portion of the Twitter button needs to be in the "your  twitter code".

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I add that. The post gets published successfully, but no prompt to tweet.

Comment: Debug it using Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: No errors come up, doesn't seem like there's anything to debug. Just to be clear, I've added this to the js: `$('#user-submitted-post').on("click",function() { 
   !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  }); ` but it doesn't seem to affect anything.